# add filter to replace part of a string

Tags: php, string, wordpress, replace

What would be the correct way to add a filter to replace part of a string in an echo?

The function is this:

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
}
```

I tried to implement this in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 'product_title_mod');
function product_title_mod($str) {
    return str_replace ('h3','h2',$str);
}
```

But that does not affect the h3 values, what would be the best way to filter those be?

Comment: You pass `$str` by value and the result of function `product_title_mod` is not utilized.

Answer (score 0):

`function` should `return` value so you can use it or `echo` value directly:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 'product_title_mod');

// option 1
function product_title_mod($str) {
    return str_replace("h3","h2",$str);
}

// option 2
function product_title_mod($str) {
    echo str_replace("h3","h2",$str);
}
```

Not totally sure how wordpress filters work, but I suppose you can't achieve what you want, because `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title` function `echo`es result directly.

Comment: I 'm not familiar with wordpress, but I think you can't do what you want, see my update.